# PHP Strings into Distinct Values

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09-29-15  11:31AM                55841 amensunset.jpg
    [1] => 09-08-15  01:55PM               260187 firstdayvpk.jpg
    [2] => 09-08-15  02:41PM            556373631 globe.psd
    [3] => 09-29-15  11:31AM               875215 keywestpkg.jpg
    [4] => 09-29-15  11:31AM                57599 revkeywestpkg.jpg
    [5] => 09-29-15  10:58AM               123836 revpizza.jpg
    [6] => 09-29-15  11:31AM                66106 revromancepkg.jpg
    [7] => 09-29-15  11:33AM               102603 revtouristpkg.jpg
    [8] => 09-29-15  11:31AM               310514 romancepkg.jpg
    [9] => 09-29-15  11:15AM               165873 SC1.jpg
    [10] => 09-29-15  11:32AM             12349206 Tarpon Creek 45.jpg
    [11] => 09-29-15  11:32AM             13813169 touristpkg.jpg
    [12] => 09-29-15  11:15AM                26340 wedding.jpg
)
```

How would I go about breaking each array value into different unique/accessible values?  (Date, Time, File Size and filename)?

Thanks in advance -

Comment: Have you tried anything? Anything at all? You could use `explode`, or `preg_match` or even `sscanf`

Comment: did you tried any thing?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with substrings and trimming, since it appears everything is the same length.

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    $parts = array("dateTime" => strtotime(substr($element, 0, 17)), "fileSize" => trim(substr($element, 17, 21)), "fileName" => trim(substr($element, 38, strlen($element)-38));
}
```

Here are all of the functions I used so you can learn more and do this all by yourself next time!

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: I was attempting to do an explode procedure - but the arbitrary number of spaces was giving me problems.  I tried then to iterate through and remove the blank entries - but wasn't working quite right.  Looked like this:

Comment: foreach ($contentsArray as $myval) {
    $testthing = explode(" ",$myval);
    foreach($testthing as $myval2) {
     if($myval2 == ' ') {
      unset($myval2);
     }
    }
    print_r($testthing);
   }

Comment: The reason I didn't go with explodes is because the filename appears to be able to have spaces. That will be tough @EZoolander

Comment: array_filter seems to remove that problem with the arbitrary number of spaces.  Maybe if I can re-key the array after that's done?

Comment: Gracias!  Yeah - running array_filter removed all the nonense, then array_values rekeyed it.  Thanks for the suggestions!